# Increase fps on video editing V2.93.2

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I just started using blender for it's video sequence editor, and downloaded it yesterday. Upon trying it out, Blender is extremely laggy, dragging my videos into edit is incredibly slow. By the time I managed to, watching the clips took forever, the fps kept fluctating from 20 fps to 2 fps. All other answers are for previous editions, is there a fix for higher fps frame rate on [this](https://www.blender.org/download/) specific version?

Comment: if it manages big videos it may become laggy I guess, you can create proxys in order to speed up the management

Comment: How would you do that? I am completely new to this

Comment: type "Blender VSE Proxy" and you should have explanations, like this video (I haven't watched it but I guess it's good): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRhTiFAHL1k ... also here (even though Blender has changed since 2015): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32203/how-do-i-use-proxies-in-the-vse-correctly

Comment: Oh so actually I have already been doing something similar to that, but the lag is still there, along with a lower render size meaning a more blurred video

Comment: ok so I don't know the other solutions, I hope someone will know, maybe Blender is not optimized for too complicated video management (the VSE is pretty convenient but I've also noticed some lagging, I don't know if it's avoidable)